# Spring MVC @RequestMapping ... using method name as action value?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Say I have this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello")
public ModelAndView hello(Model model){

    System.out.println("HelloWorldAction.sayHello");
    return null;      
}
```

Is it possible to skip the value="hello" part, and just have the @RequestMapping annotation and have spring use the method name as the value, similar to this:

```
@RequestMapping
public ModelAndView hello(Model model){

    System.out.println("HelloWorldAction.sayHello");
    return null;      
}
```

Thanks!

**===================EDIT=====================**

Tried this but not working:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="admin", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public class AdminController {

    @RequestMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> hello() { 
      System.out.println("hellooooooo");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to add "/*" on the request mapping value of the class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="admin/*")
public class AdminController {

    @RequestMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> hello() { 
      System.out.println("hellooooooo");
    }
}
```

You can go the page http://localhost:8080/website/admin/hello

Comment: I believe this only works with one action, which makes it default to that method. Cant get it to work on more actions

Comment: Why was this accepted as answer? It just works only for one method. I can say more it does **not** map request handling to method name, it passes all requests to single method regardless of path and/or method names.

Answer (score 3):

It should work if you move the RequestMethod on your specific method:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="admin")
public class AdminController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> hello() { 
      System.out.println("hellooooooo");
    }
}
```

and access it through http://hostname:port/admin/hello

Have a look here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping

Good luck