# In spring MVC, a void return type means that the view would be derived from the URL or from the method name?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am using `Spring 3.0.6`, and have noted a few (apparently) contradictory statements regarding what happens when a controller method declares a void return type (or returns a null). Consider the following :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="admin/*")
public class AdminController {

    @RequestMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> hello() { 
      System.out.println("hellooooooo");
    }
}
```

This takes the view name as the method name as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718635/spring-mvc-requestmapping-using-method-name-as-action-value). But as stated in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875255/what-does-it-mean-when-spring-mvc-controller-returns-null-view-name), the view name is derived from url (not the method name). The method in question was :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/form")
public class FormController {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processSubmit(@Valid FormBean form, 
                BindingResult result, 
                WebRequest webRequest, 
                HttpSession session, Model model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
             return null;
        } else {
            session.setAttribute("form", form);
            return "redirect:/form";            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the result when you tested it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

skaffman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6875333/280244) in [What does it mean when Spring MVC @Controller returns null view name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875255/what-does-it-mean-when-spring-mvc-controller-returns-null-view-name) is the correct one, because code can not lie.

So according to the docs and to the code: the view name is derived from the url (not from the method name).

I think that the other question ([Spring MVC @RequestMapping … using method name as action value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718635/spring-mvc-requestmapping-using-method-name-as-action-value)) (and its answer) are a bit missleading, because there the request url and the method name are the same.